# How to search for a term currently in code AND added within the last 6 months?

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I want to search source control for files with a specific term and with these conditions:

1. It has to be in the latest version of the code in the branch I'm searching. So an instance that was added 3 months ago but was removed 1 month ago should NOT count.
2. It has to have been added within the last 6 months. So an instance currently in the code that was added in 2020 should NOT count.

Is there a reasonably straightforward way to do a search like this using either the command line or any visual tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git log --all --since=6.months.ago -p --word-diff=porcelain -S term \
| awk '/^diff/ { file=substr($NF,3) } /^+/ && /term/ { print file }' | sort -u
```

will get you the list of files that have had that term added in the last six months. List the files that still have it with `git grep -l` and the common entries are your payload. You can add `--pickaxe-regex` and the log will treat `term` as a regex so you can beef up the selectivity if the bare substring match gets too much cruft.

Answer (score 2):

if you want string still here, `git grep` will help
then you blame the result of the `git grep`
you filter on the date

ggb.sh:

```
ggb() {
    limit=$(date +%s -d '-6 months' )
    echo $limit
    git grep -n $1 | while IFS=: read i j k; do
    git blame -L $j,$j $i -p|awk -v limit="$limit" -v file="$i"  'NR==1 {commit=$1} NR==8 {date=$2} END { if (date > limit) print file " " commit}'
done
}
 ggb $1
```

usage:

```
ggb.sh "foo"
```

Will output filename and commit adding the string

*Details:*

`git grep` output is read with `while IFS=: read i j k; do` loop.

Then `git blame` is used with `-p` to get porcelain output

git blame porcelain format is described [here](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5c698d947c236559e338e45c6234ece7c819338)

with awk we get the first word of the first line `NR==1 {commit=$1}`

then second work of line 8 `NR==8 {date=$2}` to get the `committer-time`

The time limit is computed with `date +%s -d '-6 months'`
then the path and the limit is used into awk command with `-v`:

`awk -v limit="$limit" -v file="$i"`